# How can I get proper Matlab syntax when typesetting Matlab source code using the algorithm package?

Tags: algorithms, sourcecode, matlab

I'm currently using the `algorithm` package for typesetting Matlab source code in my document. However, the way keywords are typeset doesn't match the Matlab syntax. For instance, `\EndFor` is typeset as "end for" instead of "end", which is the terminating keyword of a for loop in Matlab. How can I fix this?

I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\floatname{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \begin{algorithmic}\State
alpha=0;  rho=0;\State
\For {$r=1:p$}\State
    rho=rho+1/(r\^{}2);\State
    alpha=alpha+1/(r\^{}4);
\EndFor \State
\end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: You have  way too many `\State`'s. Leave the `For` in `End For`. It makes it much much clearer for the reader what exactly the `End` refers to.

Comment: But it's not a Pesudocode, and it wouldn't be right anymore (it's a Matlab Code)

Comment: Why are you formatting Matlab code as pseudo code then? Why don't you use say `listings`

Comment: Consider using the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891) of mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**: don't use `algorithm` for typesetting source code. Use either the `listings` or `minted` package instead, or (**edit**) the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see below.

---

**Detailed answer**:

You can change the way `algpseudocode`'s keywords (such as *for*, *while*, etc.) are typeset by redefining them using `algorithm`'s `\algdef` command. The following modification answers your specific question about *for* and *end for*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{For}{EndFor}[1]{\algorithmicfor\ #1}{\algorithmicend}%

\floatname{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \begin{algorithmic}\State
alpha=0;  rho=0;\State
\For {$r=1:p$}\State
    rho=rho+1/(r\^{}2);\State
    alpha=alpha+1/(r\^{}4);
\EndFor \State
\end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

**However**, while reconfiguring `algorithm` & friends to comply with some language's syntax may be possible to an extent (and at the cost of great effort and tedium), those packages are really not intended for anything other than pseudocode (i.e. "algorithms explained in plain English").

Other packages such as `listings` or `minted` are better suited for typesetting *source code* (i.e., in your case, the contents of an m-file). Those packages come with predefined settings for numerous programming languages (C, Python, Matlab, etc.), settings which can be customised. Additionally, both of those packages allow for line numbering and syntax highlighting.

**Edit**: I've recently written a package called `matlab-prettifier` for typesetting Matlab code nicely. It's built on top of the `listings` package, but I've defined a style that mimicks `minted` output, with overall better syntax-highlighting capabilities; note, in particular, that, in my example, the `end` keyword is highlighted differently, depending on the context in which it is used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}

\usepackage{filecontents} % to generate an external file from this tex file
\begin{filecontents*}{mysourcefile.m}
function I = Simprule(f,a,b,m)
% Applies the composite Simpson's rule to function f
% (using 2m+1 points) between limits a and b.
% INPUTS:
%       - f  inline function
%       - a  lower limit of the integral
%       - b  upper limit of the integral
%       - m  positive integer    
%
% OUTPUT:
%       - I  approximate value of the integral

% --- Sanity checks ---
  % 1 - Check that a<=b.
  if a>b
    error('b must be smaller than a.');
  end
  % 2 - Check that m is a positive integer.
  if (floor(m)~=m) || (m<=0) 
    error('m must be a positive integer.');
  end

% --- Create subintervals of [a,b] ---
  x = linspace(a,b,2*m+1);
  h = (b-a)/(2*m);

% --- Apply the composite Simpson's rule ---
    int = (h/3)*(   f(x(1))...                       
                    + 2 * sum( f(x(3:2:end-2)) )...
                    + 4 * sum( f(x(2:2:end-1)) )...
                    + f(x(end))  );

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-Pyglike,basicstyle=\mlttfamily]{mysourcefile.m}
\end{document}
```

I've generated the `m`-file fromn within my `tex` file, just for completeness of my example. In practice, you would have your `m`-files sitting somewhere on your machine and you would just link to them inside your input file.

---

Finallly, a comment that is only peripheral to the main topic here (TeX): **Matlab loops are slow!** For improved performance, you should, whenever possible, avoid using Matlab (`for` or `while`) loops and use, instead, a combination of the colon operator and vectorised commands (such as `sum`). Here is the alternative I would recommend:

[image]

The reduction in computation time of my version over yours becomes significant as `p` increases.

Comment: I tried the listings before, but I can't install the usepackage. I always get the following error message: ! Package caption Error: For a successful cooperation we need at least version `2004/02/13 v1.2' of package listings,

Comment: Have you tried updating your TeX distribution?

Comment: @little_miss_sunshine What Jubobs says. If a package demands a 2004 version of another package and you don't have it, it's time to re-install ;)

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier?lang=en